# How to solve session_generate_id exception in magento2?

Tags: magento2, session

Getting error

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed.  ID: user (path: D:\Projects\xampp\tmp) in `\vendor\magento\framework\Session\SessionManager.php` on line 504

Comment: It is occurred occasionally or have some specific scenario for it ?!

Comment: occasionally   , same code work fine sometime

Answer (score 0):

You May want to refer here for the solution :
https://mage2.pro/t/topic/4661